# How to filter data by pm(time) in oracle?

Tags: oracle9i

I have a table in which I have inserted trainno and its time of arrival now I need to display trains which arrived on PM.
I have tried this
`select trainno,to_char(timeofarrival,'HH:MI:SS A.M.')"toa" from train
where to_char(timeofarrival,'HH:MI:SS A.M.')='P.M.';`
[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the `toa` column?  Oracle does not have a `time` data type.  Are those `date` values where the day is not displayed?  Are they `varchar2` strings?  An `interval day to second`?  Something else?

Comment: @JustinCave Datatype is date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sincce `timeOfArrival` is a date

```
WHERE to_number( to_char( timeOfArrival, 'HH24' )) >= 12
```

will give you the rows where the time component is after noon.